# Перемещение по веткам GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-branch

1. Создал локальный репозиторий и залил его на GitHub
2. Далее на GitHub-е создал ветку `branch : gh-pages`
3. Перенёс *(перетянул)* туда необходимый файл

Теперь хочу через GitBush переключиться на ветку `branch : gh-pages`, но при вводе `git branch` показывает, что есть только ветка мастер.

```
$ git branch
* master
```

Последние изменения скачал через `git pull`, и строка с новой веткой есть

`git * [new branch]      gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages`

Подскажите, как выйти на `gh-pages`, и где я мог напортачить >_< ?

Comment: 1. `$ man git-branch` на предмет опций `-l`, `-r` и `-a`. 2. `$ git checkout gh-pages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

команда `branch` программы *git* без опций (или с опцией `-l`) покажет только локальные ветки.

с опцией `-r` покажет только удалённые ветки, а с опцией `-a` — и те и другие.

```
$ git branch -a
```

---

для переключения между ветками служит команда `checkout` с параметром — именем ветки, которую хотите сделать текущей.

если локальной ветки с таким именем не существует, но существует удалённая ветка (с таким именем), будет создана локальная ветка, указывающая на тот же самый коммит, что и удалённая, причём локальная ветка сразу же будет «привязана» (bind) к удалённой. это как раз то, что вам и требуется.

```
$ git checkout gh-pages
```

Comment: Большое спасибо )))